# Two authors with same name – multiple author citations

Tags: citation-style

I'm formatting a paper right now and there are two authors with the surname "Moran". I know that the usual way of going about that is to add the initial to each citation (J. Moran 2015; D. Moran 2014). But what is the standard way of doing that if one of the authors is also part of a three-author citation (e.g. Peters, (D.) Moran and Seegers)? Does the initial of the Moran that is referred to here also need to be included? Or is it unnecessary since it is clear from the two other names which work is referenced?
I'm using Chicago author-date style (16th edition).

Comment: It seems to me that, unless you have a 'Peters, D. Moran and Seegers' and a 'Peters, J. Moran and Seegers' there is no confusion with dropping the initial in the multi-author citation. The full citation (endnote, footnote) will have all the initials and be clear.

Comment: Cite "Morans" ahahah sorry I had to do it. hope i don't get banned for that. On/off topic, it seems that i may write a paper together with my twin who's in a different field/institution than i am. That'll be hell for people to cite.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Chicago, but the APA Style [says](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2018/02/whats-in-a-name-authors-with-the-same-surname.html): "Never include initials for second or subsequent authors in in-text citations."

Comment: That's good to know, thanks for that! I'll go with that rule then for now